# How to enable checkbox when checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkme"/>
<p class="label-text"><b>By checking this, you agree to our <a href="terms.html" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin',
'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0'); return false;" style="color: red;">Terms &amp; <br>Conditions</a>&nbsp;and&nbsp;<a href="privacy.html" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin',
'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0'); return false;" style="color: red;">Privacy Policy</a></b></p>
<input class="formBtn" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
var checker = document.getElementById('checkme');
var sendbtn = document.getElementById('submit');
checker.onchange = function(){
     if(this.checked){
          sendbtn.disabled = false;
     } else {
          sendbtn.disabled = true;
};
```

**jQuery**

```
$( "#checkme" ).on( "click", function() {
        if($( "#checkme:checked" ).length > 0) {
               $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
        } else{
               $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
        }  
});
```

All not working. Please help.

Also help me add in the javascript a class for css to make the button transparent when disabled. Thanks a lot!

Comment: two things: you need to make sure your `script` tag comes *after* the html elements you're dealing with (unless you use something like a `$(document).ready()`). Second, your JavaScript block is missing the close brace for the `onchange` handler function. With those two changes, it worked properly for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Javascript Solution

I just kept it simple with regular javascript.  I added an onclick function to the checkbox that enables the submit when the checkbox is checked.
Hope it helps.

```js
function checkA(){
if(document.getElementById('checkme').checked == true){   
document.getElementById('submit').disabled = "";
} else {
document.getElementById('submit').disabled = "disabled";}}
```

```html
<input onclick="checkA();" type="checkbox" id="checkme">
<p class="label-text"><b>By checking this, you agree to our <a href="terms.html" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin',
'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0'); return false;" style="color: red;">Terms &amp; <br>Conditions</a>&nbsp;and&nbsp;<a href="privacy.html" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin',
'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0'); return false;" style="color: red;">Privacy Policy</a></b></p>
<input class="formBtn" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled">
```

Comment: No problem glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `change` not `click` and to add style to the `disabled` input you can simply use `#submit[disabled]`

```js
$( "#checkme" ).on( "change", function() {
  $('#submit').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
}).change(); // use this to run change event on load
```

```css
#submit{
  transition-duration : 0.5s;
}
#submit[disabled]{
  opacity : 0.5;
  transition-duration : 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkme"/>
<p class="label-text"><b>By checking this, you agree to our <a href="terms.html" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin',
'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0'); return false;" style="color: red;">Terms &amp; <br>Conditions</a>&nbsp;and&nbsp;<a href="privacy.html" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin',
'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0'); return false;" style="color: red;">Privacy Policy</a></b></p>
<input class="formBtn" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

To simplify your code you can use `$('#submit').prop('disabled', !this.checked);` `this.checked` will return true when checked and false when unchecked so you can use `!` before it to reverse it

> **Note**: be sure you include jquery

To add an effect to the input while disabled true/false  you can add something like `transition-duration : 0.5s;`

Comment: You're welcome @crosse .. I voted your question up to let you upvote Jonny's answer .. Have a great day :-)